# MVC jqueryUI modal dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

So in all my failed attempts to get jQueryUI working, I have tried this example [here](http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/?p=280) after downloading a theme from the jQueryUI site.

and here is my code looking at that example in the link above in my asp.net mvc page.

```
<link type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js")%>"></script>



<script>

$('#dialog_link').click(function(){
    $('#Dialog').dialog('open');  
    return false;
});


</script>

<p id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</p> 


<div id="Dialog" title="Dialog title!">
This content shown within dialog...

</div>
```

After hitting F5 I would have expected to see a clickable text which when clicked would bring up a modal dialog with a [x] button to close it and get back to the main window. However what I get to see is this on page load,

[image: screenshot of mvc application]

where the text 'open dialog' does not respond to click events and the supposed "modal dialog" is already visible in the form of a plain string and without any formatting. So where did all the magic of jQueryUI go? Something wrong in my linking correct scripts? 
Totally lost. Please help..

**Edit**
This exact same code works in pure html mode in a different file. when I copy this code into my asp.net mvc page within the content tags I get a javascript error at a non-descript line!!

Comment: What JavaScript errors are you seeing on the page? I suspect that your path to jQueryUI is not correct.

Comment: no javascript errors at all... the paths are correct. But are those the correct files I should be linking?

Comment: This http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ tutorial is much better and up to date ;)

Comment: ok now I am seeing the error ... Webpage error details

Message: Invalid character
Line: 26
Char: 4
Code: 0

There is nothing on line 26 however...

Comment: @MikeSW: I tried going by the example there.. but the css doesnt look like it should and the modal dialog shows up on page load, without waiting for any button/link click event...

Comment: Have you read the entire page? Is the official page of jquery UI Dialog. Best of all, do a copy/paste of their code, that it works

Comment: Try directly linking to a CDN with jQueryUI instead of your local copy. I have a feeling you aren't including it correctly

Comment: @andrew: This exact same code works in pure html mode in a different file. when I copy this code into my asp.net mvc page within the content tags I get a javascript error at a non-descript line!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the 'open' out of your $('#Dialog').dialog('open'); and you are good to go.

Edit: Added this jsFiddle with your code as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DoomHamster/LhJsL/1/

Also, you don't need 'return false' when clicking an element with no default click event.

EDIT: From your comment below I suspect that you are having issues with loading jQuery and jQueryUI in the first place.  Try replacing your script and css links with the following as a test to eliminate path issues:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the click event did not work. The dialog is invisible now after applying the style

Comment: @user20358 the dialog should be invisible until it is displayed.  The .dialog() method will make it visible.  As far as the click not working, are you getting any js errors in the browser console?  Is your code significantly different than what you posted? Because using that code in my jsFiddle seemed to work.  if the code is the same, I suspect a path issue preventing your js files from loading.

Comment: @user20358 See my edit above for a test to make sure that you are loading the libraries correctly.

Comment: the dialog being hidden is ok. That is how I wanted it. There is no other code in my page. I have removed everything from the page and made it hold just those bits that I have posted above. Even when pointing to the google ajax library above I get the same error on line 26.. the funny part is line 26 is  empty .. there is nothing on line 26 ..not even a single charachter.. still I get an error " Message: Invalid character Line: 26 Char: 4 Code: 0 "

Comment: the problem seems to be really silly. I had commented the local jquery include statements after adding references to the googleapis ones.. the comments were aspx + html + javascript comments.. looks like commenting javascript includes doesnt work.. I didnt know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function()
{
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
    $('#Dialog').dialog();  
   return false;
    });
})
```